# Get the LatLngBouds from a camera position

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get the `LatLng` of the top right corner and bottom left corner of a Google Map frame to create a `LatLngBounds`. Is it possible to do that?

[image: map]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can easily be determined using the Map View API:

```
yourMapFragment.getMap().getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds
```

Which the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion) state is:

> The smallest bounding box that includes the visible region defined in this class.

Alternatively, you can also get the individual corners of the projection by replacing `latLngBounds` with `farLeft`, `farRight`, `nearLeft` or `nearRight`

In your case, you can simply use

```
LatLng bottomLeft = 
yourMapFragment.getMap().getProjection().getVisibleRegion().nearLeft;

LatLng topRight = 
yourMapFragment.getMap().getProjection().getVisibleRegion().farRight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You have the `Visible Region Object`, that has the coordinates of all the four angles. Please refer to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion).